# sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) vs sizeof(a)/sizeof(t) where t is type in C from K.N.King

Tags: c, array

I'm trying to understand why `sizeof(a)/sizeof(t)` is inferior for getting the length of an array to `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` if just as it's possible to have different types, my elements could also be of different lengths. so what makes dividing by the element size uniform?

Comment: To help people understand your question, please explain where `a` and `t` come from. Give multiple examples. In particular, explain what `a` and `t` would be, if someone passes in: (1) an array typedef, (2) an array instance, (3) a pointer. Please remember that most people do not have the same "K.N.King" book as yours. If your question depends on something from that book, be sure to explain it here.

Comment: If it is a C macro, give the definition of the macro, and give examples of how the macro is used.

Comment: An array contains elements of a single type. The size of a type is a constant.

Comment: I'm disappointed with the communities reception of this question. This is not asking us to write or explain code.

Comment: @candied_orange: nevertheless it is badly written and lacks any sign of improvement by the OP, though the question got some helpful comments.

Comment: @DocBrown can't disagree there but if that's your close reason use the "other" option. Confusing the newbies doesn't build the community.

Comment: @candied_orange: fully agree to you. Disclaimer:I did not mistake this for a coding question, and did not vote so. I voted for closing with the "needs details or clarity" reason, but retracted my close vote since it seems the question is clear enough to generate at least one good answer. But I still left my downvote in place. Gnat, do you hear me: this is not a coding question (at least not one for which the default close reason applies)!

Answer (score 8):

The difference between `sizeof(a)/sizeof(t)` and `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` is that for the first one you need to supply two pieces of information (the array name and the type of its elements) while the second one needs only a single piece of information (the array name).

The more pieces of information you need to provide, the more chance there is that a mistake is made. To make matters worse, if a mistake is made in the element type of the array, there is no safety net to catch that mistake. You will just get incorrect results.

And a mistake does not mean only when the code initially gets written, but also when later on changes are mode to it.

Suppose you start out with

```
int arr[N];
…
array_length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
```

later on you find that `int` isn't the right type, because you also need to store fractional numbers, so you change it to `double`, but you forget the sizeof expression:

```
double arr[N];
…
array_length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
```

Now suddenly, the value of `array_length` is no longer correct. If you had written it as `array_length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);`, then that mistake could not have happened.

Comment: It could be argued that a name change is far more likely than a type change. But a name change is an automated refactoring. Even if done by hand, a mistake would produce a compiler error. So I'm strongly in the `a[0]` camp. Code should welcome refactoring.

Comment: @candied_orange I personally prefer trimming it down to `sizeof a / sizeof *a` as I dislike senseless verbosity, not that it changes anything much.

Comment: @Deduplicator I’ve heard that debased as well. Some like it short. Some think the long one makes it clearer that you’re looking at the size of an element. Personally I wish the whole thing was hidden behind a good abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider the pros/cons from a **reviewer** point of view.

```
size_t a_size1 = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
size_t a_size2 = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
```

The type definition of `a` may not be near these lines of code, perhaps in a .h file.

To check either line of code, we need to know if `a` is in fact an array and not a pointer.  This is a binary consideration that is usually understood in review - not much cost.

Yet `sizeof(int)` obliges another check: does the type match?  For the original coder, this is not much of issue and so may appear inconsequential.  Yet for a *reviewer who has cursory knowledge* of the code, it is a tedious check.

This is a similar concern of [@Bart van Ingen Schenau](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/409387/94903) good answer, yet I wanted to emphasize the increased negative impact on reviewers.